# How to encrypt data in objective c and decrypt in mac using terminal

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, iphone-sdk-3.0, rncryptor

I am trying to encrypt the file using RnCryptor in objective and decrypting it in mac using following command in terminal

Encryption code in objective c

```
NSData *encryptedData =[RNEncryptor encryptData:fileData withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:aPassword error:&error];
```

Terminal command for mac

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in /Users/Desktop/Log.txt  -out  /Users/Desktop/Log1.txt
```

but end in error bad magic number.

Answer (score 1):

RNCryptor and OpenSSL have different formats. There is a very simple command-line version of RNCryptor in the [RNCryptor-objc repository](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-objc/tree/master/rncrypt). I don't believe anyone has written a full-featured command-line client.